# How to scroll down to div when input focused

Tags: scroll, focus

Can anyone help me with a javascript to make the page scroll down to the searchbox when the searchfield is focused? Like if you click on the searchfield, the position changes, until the red and yellow boxes are out of sight.

```css
#overtop {
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}

#top {
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
background: yellow;
}

#searchbox {

}

#content {
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="overtop">
</div>
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="searchbox">
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="enter.." title="search">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: added the html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got it, finally.

```
        $("#myInput").click(function () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#searchbox").offset().top }, 300);
    return true;
});
```